# Override what component implementation is injected for nested/transitive dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Say I've got two classes that are instantiated by Castle Windsor, and each has a dependency on the same interface:

- `FooRepo` → `IApiClient`
- `BarRepo` → `IApiClient`

In this case `IApiClient` is implemented by one class, `GenericApiClient`, that knows how to communicate with any API. However, I want to create different instances of `GenericApiClient` that are passed different config values (exposed via `IApiClientConfiguration`) so that `FooRepo` talks to the Foo API endpoint and the `BarRepo` talks to the Bar API endpoint:

- `FooRepo` → `IApiClient (GenericApiClient)` → `IApiClientConfiguration (FooClientConfiguration)`
- `BarRepo` → `IApiClient (GenericApiClient)` → `IApiClientConfiguration (BarClientConfiguration)`

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(
    Component.For<HomeController>().LifeStyle.Transient,
    Component.For<FooRepo>()
        .LifeStyle.Transient,
    Component.For<BarRepo>()
        //.DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IApiClientConfiguration, BarClientConfiguration>()) // this does nothing cause the client config is not a direct dependency :(
        .LifeStyle.Transient,
    Component.For<IApiClient>()
        .ImplementedBy<GenericApiClient>()
        //.DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IApiClientConfiguration, BarClientConfiguration>()) // this overrides for both FooRepo and BarRepo :(
        .LifeStyle.Transient,
    Component.For<IApiClientConfiguration>()
        .ImplementedBy<FooClientConfiguration>()
        .LifeStyle.Transient,
    Component.For<IApiClientConfiguration>()
        .ImplementedBy<BarClientConfiguration>()
        .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the `FooRepo` to get an instance of `GenericApiClient` configured with `FooClientConfiguration`, with `BarRepo` getting a `BarClientConfiguration`:

- By default they both get `FooClientConfiguration` since that's what's registered first
- I can override the config for `IApiClient` using `DependsOn(...)`, but that applies to both `FooRepo` and `BarRepo`
- If I use `DependsOn(...)` on the `BarRepo`, it has no effect

(In case the above question is not clear, I have a minimum working example [here](https://github.com/mkropat/WindsorTransitiveDependencyOverrideMWE/blob/master/WindsorTransitiveDependencyOverride/Global.asax.cs))

Is there some way I can configure Castle Windsor to do what I want? Is there some way to better structure my code so I don't have this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IApiClientConfiguration>()
        .ImplementedBy<FooClientConfiguration>()
        .Named("FooConfiguration")
        .LifestyleTransient(),
    Component.For<IApiClientConfiguration>()
        .ImplementedBy<BarClientConfiguration>()
        .Named("BarConfiguration")
        .LifestyleTransient(),
    Component.For<IApiClient, GenericApiClient>()
        .Named("FooClient")
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(
            typeof(IApiClientConfiguration), "FooConfiguration")),
    Component.For<IApiClient, GenericApiClient>()
        .Named("BarClient")
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(
            typeof(IApiClientConfiguration), "BarConfiguration")),
    Component.For<FooRepo>()
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IApiClient), "FooClient")),
    Component.For<BarRepo>()
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IApiClient), "BarClient"))
    );
```

It's not pretty. And there may be a way to simplify the syntax a little. Windsor usually offers a few different ways to do everything.

You're defining two different implementations of `GenericApiClient`, and for each you're specifying which configuration to use. Then, when registering `FooRepo` and `BarRepo`, for each of them you're specifying which named implementation of `IApiClient` to use.

If one or the other is the default then you can indicate it using `IsDefault()` and only name the other. It can also be easier to follow if you write separate installers for separate groups of implementations, or even just methods in the same installer, like

```
RegisterFooDependencies(IWindsorContainer container)
{
    container.Register(
        Component.For<IApiClientConfiguration>()
            .ImplementedBy<FooClientConfiguration>()
            .Named("FooConfiguration")
            .LifestyleTransient(),
        Component.For<IApiClient, GenericApiClient>()
            .Named("FooClient")
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(
                typeof(IApiClientConfiguration), "FooConfiguration")),
        Component.For<FooRepo>()
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IApiClient), "FooClient"))          
    );
}
```

Comment: Cool, that makes sense. Create different named components for `IApiClient` and add the override to each named version. I wonder if there's a way to do it without naming the `IApiClientConfiguration` components. P.S. I had to make a slight change to get your code to run... hope you don't mind that I edited it in.

Comment: Not at all. I did some more reading because I wouldn't want to abandon hope of finding a simpler way. But I didn't turn up anything right away.

Comment: FYI [this simplification](https://github.com/mkropat/WindsorTransitiveDependencyOverrideMWE/commit/68fdab3c4621c26bd45636b108c4c4c0a65f1c06) seems to work for my case.

Comment: One thing to watch out for - this bit me once: If you register two components for one dependency, be sure to mark one of them `IsDefault()` unless you're *always* specifying a name. Otherwise when you request a dependency that isn't specified with a name, the selection of the component can be non-deterministic. It's less likely when it's all in one installer. But you could test over and over and it behaves as expected, then in a different environment it selects the other dependency. So it's best to always be explicit.

Comment: That also protects you against someone else adding another installer that registers a different implementation. You make yours the default and if someone else wants a different one they are forced to specify it by name.

Answer (score 1):

The answer @Scott-Hannen gave is *technically* correct and he's also correct when he says

> It's not pretty.

Windsor is very flexible and you can, with enough configuration and extensions, make it do a lot, but should you?

Usually if things get too complicated and you find having yourself having problems explaining to a tool how your architecture is put together, perhaps it's too complicated to explain to, and maintain by humans?

You have two sets of abstractions, that always go together (your `Repo` and `IApiClientConfiguration`) separated by another abstraction `IApiClient`.

If they go hand in hand I would put them side by side, and rearrange the dependency chain such that you end up with something similar to:

```
public FooRepo(IApiClient client, FooClientConfiguration clientConfig)
{
   // ...stuff, and then
   client.Configure(config);
}
```

Now you're making the relationship explicit and obvious to any human reading your code. And, as a side-benefit, your Windsor configuration will become trivial as well.

Comment: Nice. For a little added class complexity you can greatly simplify the Windsor complexity. That seems like a good trade off.

Comment: More importantly, you're making the relationships in your code more explicit and your code easier to follow

Comment: I agree that my answer introduced a bunch of ugly complexity. I was answering literally and didn't see the forest for the trees. But I think that if 1) `FooRepo` depends on something which also requires a client configuration and 2) `FooRepo` is responsible for somehow configuring that dependency then `IApiClient` isn't really a good abstraction. It can't be replaced by something that *isn't* an API client and *doesn't* need that configuration. `FooRepo` shouldn't know or care about the dependencies of its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I read the answer from @Krzysztof Kozmic. I agree with the point - my accepted answer, while, technically correct, requires some complicated configuration.

I'm not sure I agree with having a class configure its own dependencies. If we do this:

```
public FooRepo(IApiClient client, FooClientConfiguration clientConfig)
{
   // ...stuff, and then
   client.Configure(config);
}
```

then `FooRepo` knows too much about `IApiClient`. It knows that it requires a client configuration. It's less of an abstraction. I didn't point this out in my initial answer, but why should `FooRepo` even know that what it depends on is an API client at all, let alone an API client that requires a configuration?

So while my first answer was literal - how to make Windsor do what was asked - here's a better way to solve the original problem:

First, don't make `FooRepo` or `BarRepo` dependent on `IApiClient`. They shouldn't know anything about API clients. They just depend on something that provides a service, somehow. Perhaps something like this:

```
public interface IFooService
```

Then the implementation is this:

```
public class FooApiClient : GenericApiClient, IFooService
{
    public FooApiClient() : base(new FooClientConfiguration())
    {}

    // Whatever IFooService does    
}
```

I get carried away with doing *everything* with dependency injection. But in this case, for the sake of readability, we could just create a class that composes an API client with a given configuration.

`FooApiClient` is coupled to `FooClientConfiguration` (the sort of thing we usually try to avoid with DI) but that is its purpose - to provide that coupled configuration so that it doesn't exist in either the DI configuration or in classes that depend on it.

Now that messy stuff is moved out of the DI configuration, and `FooRepo` is even simpler because it's depending on a *true* abstraction, not something that has an `I` in front of it but really represents a concrete implementation (an API client.)